# Beamer "show notes on second screen" with XeLaTeX and "AtBeginSection"

Tags: beamer, xetex, pdfpages

I am using `beamer` with XeLaTeX. With every new section I add a dedicated section page to my presentation. Now I started to add notes to my presentation and want to use the `show notes on second screen` option, because the software I use for presentation works very well with this format. Unfortunately the result is that the content of the frames following a section slide is not shown.

It does work properly with LuaTeX and pdfTeX.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\AtBeginSection{
    \frame{\insertsectionhead}
}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section}
\begin{frame}{My Frametitle}
    My Content
\end{frame}
\note{
    My Notes
}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: No content shown]

Seems like a bug. Any ideas for a fix/workaround?

Comment: Fascinating! In the little preview window on the note slide the content is rendered as it should.

Comment: Right. I also noticed something else. If you replace `My Content` with `\textcolor{normal text.fg}{My Content}` the text also appears on the "main slide".

Comment: I just had a closer look at the pdf. "My Content" is actually there, but the font colour is white.

Comment: Ok, interesting. So here is another thing I noticed: The items of an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment are typeset properly. But the items in a  `description` are also white. The same applies to formulas – they are also white.

Comment: I think the `section`-stuff is not relevant to this problem, it also shows in `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}
 
\frame{test}

\frame{test}

\end{document}`

Comment: You find presentation.app, it the good tool for this http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its seems something with the font colour is broken, so that the text is displayed in white.

**Workaround**

Reset the font colour in every frame. The following code adds `\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}` to the definition of a slide (taken from `beamerbaseframe.sty`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\AtBeginSection{
    \frame{\insertsectionhead}
}

\makeatletter

\renewenvironment{beamer@frameslide}{%
    \ifbeamer@autobreak\else%
    \ifx\beamer@againname\@empty%
    {\let\@elt\beamer@restorecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
    \else%
    {\let\@elt\beamer@labelrestorecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
    \global\c@beamerpauses=1\relax%
    \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{%
        \stepcounter{subsectionslide}%
        \xdef\beamer@framestartpage{\the\c@page}% only first time
    }{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}% cleanup from previous slide
    \hypersetup{pdfpagetransition=R}%
    \hypersetup{pdfpageduration=}%
    \@ifundefined{thispdfpagelabel}{}{%
        \thispdfpagelabel{\insertframenumber}}%
    \xdef\beamer@frameendpage{\the\c@page}% every time
    \beamer@setuplinks%
    \beamer@displaybreak%
    \global\setbox\beamer@zoombox=\box\voidb@x%
    \def\beamer@zoomer{}%
    \beamer@slidehaszoomfalse%
    \gdef\insertframetitle{}%
    \gdef\insertframesubtitle{}%
    \gdef\beamer@frametitle{}%
    \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{}%
    \gdef\beamer@framesubtitle{}%
    \let\beamer@startcomment=\beamer@startcommentinframe%
    % Start slide:
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}% NEW
    \beamer@framenotesbegin%
    \global\setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox\bgroup%
    \beamer@inframetrue%
    \let\frame=\framelatex% inside frames, use LaTeX's \frame command
    \begin{beamer@framepauses}%
        \refcounter{framenumber}%use frame number for  \label
        \ifbeamer@shrink%
        \hsize=\beamer@shrinkfactorinv\hsize%
        \textwidth=\beamer@shrinkfactorinv\textwidth%
        \linewidth=\beamer@shrinkfactorinv\linewidth%
        \fi%
        % Insert labels if necessary:
        \ifx\beamer@againname\@empty\else%
        \nointerlineskip\vbox to0pt{\vss%
            \label<\the\beamer@slideinframe>{\beamer@againname<\the\beamer@slideinframe>}%
            \ifnum\beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
            \label<1>{\beamer@againname}%
            \fi%
        }\nointerlineskip%
        \fi%
        \ifx\beamer@framehypertargets\@empty\else%
        \nointerlineskip\vbox to0pt{\vss%
            \beamer@framehypertargets%
            \global\let\beamer@framehypertargets\@empty%
        }\nointerlineskip%
        \fi%
        \vskip-\parskip\vbox{}%
        \beamer@initfirstlineunskip%
        \ifbeamer@plainframe\nointerlineskip\fi%
        \beamer@checkframetitle}%
    {\par
    \end{beamer@framepauses}%
    \egroup%
    \ifx\beamer@frametitle\@empty%
    \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\box\voidb@x%
    \else%
    \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\vbox{%
        \vbox{}%
        {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{frametitle}\vskip0.25em}%
    }%
    \fi%
    \ifbeamer@plainframe%
    \beamer@frametextheight=\paperheight%
    \else%
    \beamer@frametextheight=\textheight%
    \fi%
    \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\ht\beamer@frametitlebox%
    \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\dp\beamer@frametitlebox%
    \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\beamer@frametopskip%
    \ifbeamer@shrink%
    \beamer@shrinkframebox%
    \fi%
    \ifx\beamer@zoomer\@empty
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox{%
        \nobreak\vbox{}\nobreak\par\nobreak\beamer@entrycode\nobreak%
        \nointerlineskip\unvbox\beamer@frametitlebox%
        \nobreak%
        \ifbeamer@autobreak%
        \vskip\beamer@frametopskipautobreak%
        \else%
        \vskip\beamer@frametopskip%
        \fi%
        \nobreak%
        \nointerlineskip\box\beamer@zoombox\nointerlineskip%
        \nobreak%
        \ifbeamer@slidehaszoom\box\beamer@framebox\else\unvbox\beamer@framebox\fi%
        % bottom skip is added in autobreakframebox
    }%
    \beamer@autobreakframebox%
    \else%
    \beamer@zoomer%
    \fi%
    \beamer@undolabels%
    \beamer@framenotesend%
    \box\beamer@framebox}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{My Section}
\begin{frame}{My Frametitle}
    My Content
    \note{hgv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

In comments @Benjamin suggested this much simpler solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\AtBeginSection{
    \frame{\insertsectionhead}
}

\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
     \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
      \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}% 
      \gdef\beamer@notes{}% 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{My Section}
    \begin{frame}{My Frametitle}
        My Content
        \note{hgv}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work. But why not redefine `\def\beamer@framenotesbegin`? `\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
  \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
  \gdef\beamer@notes{}%
}
\makeatother` This would make the workaround so much shorter. Or do you see any downside of this?

Comment: @Benjamin That's probably easier. I just tried out a few locations to change the colour until it worked

Comment: Just stubled over the same problem -- many thanks for the work around! Did you report the bug to the maintainers at https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issues ?

Comment: @Florian I don't know if there is a buck report about this, you should ask the OP Benjamin if he filled one.

Comment: @Benjamin see the comment of Florian

Comment: @Florian No, I haven't filed a bug report. I have a lot of work right now, so please feel free to file one.

Comment: Just a note that it seems this bug still exists in Tex Live 2018

Comment: @Skyork If you need something to look forward: the bug will still be there in TL2020 :) https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337

Comment: Note: this answer gave me some ‘overfull \vbox’ errors and modified the top bar of my presentation. However the following slightly modified version worked successfully: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337#issuecomment-896438488