# Issues with Beamer Notes and LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, luatex, babel, hebrew

I encountered some issues when using Beamer Notes with LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX.

### Issue with LuaLaTeX:

MWE1 - LuaLaTeX + Notes + Babel with Hebrew as main page = Invisible note

Removing the language lines of code (`babel`) solves the problem.

```
% Compile with LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{beamer}
%:Notes
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
%------
% Problematic addition which causes invisible notes:
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=en]{english}
\babelfont{sf}{Arimo}
%------
\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{1} 
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
1&2\\
\end{tabular}
}
\note{comment}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE1]

### Issue with XeLaTeX:

MWE1 - XeLaTeX + Notes + \titlepage = Invisible table.

Removing the **`\titlepage`** from document body solves the above problem.

### MWE2 - XeLaTeX:

```
% Compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{beamer}
%:Notes
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\frame{
\frametitle{1} 
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
1&2\\
\end{tabular}
}
\note{comment}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

Although the issue in MWE2 can be solved (as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288408/beamer-show-notes-on-second-screen-with-xelatex-and-atbeginsection)) by adding the following lines of code to the preamble:

```
\AtBeginSection{
    \frame{\insertsectionhead}
}

\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
     \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
      \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}% 
      \gdef\beamer@notes{}% 
}
\makeatother
```

the issue was less specific there.

Comment: For lualatex adding `\pagedir TLT` and `\bodydir TLT` at the begining solve the issue, if you need a `TRT` pagedir and bodydir I have reported a bug  on github  not  yet solved caused with `pgfpages` in right to left documents
https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/911

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. It doesn't work.

Comment: `\pagedir TLT \bodydir TLT` just after `\begin{document}` or define english as main language not hebrew.

Answer (score 1):

```
% Compile with LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{beamer-rl}
\usepackage{pgfpages-rl}
%:Notes
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
%------
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=en]{english}
\babelfont{sf}{Arimo}
%------
\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{1} 
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|}
1&2\\
\end{tabular}
}
\note{comment}
\end{document}
```